# Angular e2e test timeout problem while login

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I have a problem with writting a angulae e2e protractor test, i always get a timeout error while trying to test a login with correct email and password.

```
describe("login view", () => {
  const app = new App();
  const login = new LoginPage();

  beforeAll(() => {
    app.navigateTo(BASE_URL);
    app.clearLocalStorage();
  });

  it("should login successfully", async () => {
    await Promise.all([login.clearPassword(), login.clearUsername()]);
    login.username = E2E_USERNAME;
    login.password = E2E_PASSWORD;
    login.submit.click();
    const currentUrl = await app.currentUrl;
    expect(currentUrl).toEqual(LABORATORIES_URL);
  });
```

```
export class LoginPage {
  private usernameInput = element(by.id("loginFormUsernameInput"));
  private passwordInput = element(by.id("loginFormPasswordInput"));
  private confirmButton = element(by.id("loginFormConfirmButton"));
  
  public set username(username: string) {
    this.usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
  }
  public set password(password: string) {
    this.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
  }
  public get submit(): ElementFinder {
    return this.confirmButton;
  }
}
```

I'm working on node: 10.19.0.
package.json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
```

looking for a solution for this problem, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the definition of your `login.clearUsername()` and `login.clearPassword()`?

Or maybe, instead of using `await Promise.all([login.clearPassword(), login.clearUsername()]);` in the spec file, it is a good idea to change your getters a little, like this.

```
 public set username(username: string) {
    this.usernameInput.clear();
    this.usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
  }
  public set password(password: string) {
    this.passwordInput.clear();
    this.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
  }
```